# SyntaxError: invalid syntax, python, query API

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-3.4

I'm learning how to query an API programmatically using python.  I'm able to authenticate against the API and get a 200 response.

When I pass through parameters like this:

```
parameters = {"q": "serial_number:actual_serial"}
```

and then `print(response.text)` I get data back that I expect.

When I pass through parameters like this:

```
parameters = {"q": "serial_number:actual_serial"&"rows=5"}
```

I get:

```
    parameters = {"q": "serial_number:actual_serial"&"rows=5"}
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

and when I try to use a comma:

```
parameters = {"q": "serial_number:actual_serial", "rows=5"}
```

I get

```
    parameters = {"q": "serial_number:actual_serial", "rows=5"}
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I'm not formatting the second part of the parameters properly. What am I missing?

I'm using python3.4

When I query using the web API for the same query, I get an URL that is:
`https://.......?q=state%3APENDING_DESTRUCTION&rows=5&......` (sorry, obfuscating the url).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid Python, no. You **must** provide `key: value` pairs in a dictionary, separated by commas. Your second section, after the comma, has no `key: value` pair.

If `row` is another parameter, with the value `5`, put that into the Python dictionary as a key-value pair:

```
parameters = {"q": "serial_number:actual_serial", "row": 5}
```

The `requests` library then takes care of converting that dictionary to the right URL query string.

Comment: Marking as correct, my parameters now work correctly and thank you for the clear explanation. I continue to struggle with formatting for dictionaries and lists.